# Find by similar filenames on macOS?

Tags: macos, duplicate-files

There are plenty of apps that find duplicate files, however I haven't found any that work based on filename only comparison.

There appears to be [an app for Windows](http://www.joerg-rosenthal.com/en/antitwin/) that does this:

[image: Anti-Twin]

But out of all of the various apps for macOS, there doesn't appear to be one. I'd even be happy for a shell app (*nix) that works on macOS.

Comment: Are you looking to find duplicates between 2 trees or all the duplicates in a single one?

Comment: Both or recursively under the same tree branch.  Perhaps most frequently I'll be looking in a singular tree and only in the same 1st level, but I will want to do the others as well @SteveBarnes.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are on macOS you already have python installed so a simple python script can do the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import sys
from collections import defaultdict
def get_fnames(fnamedict, treeroot="."):
    """ Traverse a directory tree putting locations into a dictionary """
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(treeroot):
        for fname in files:
            fnamedict[fname].append(root)

def print_dups(fnamedict):
    """ Given a dictionary of filenames & paths output any names with more than one path """
    dupsfound = False
    for fname, paths in fnamedict.items():
        if len(paths) > 1:
            print("{} occurs {} times:".format(fname, len(paths)))
            print("\t{}".format('\n\t'.join(paths)))
            dupsfound = True
    if not dupsfound:
        print("No Duplicate Names Found")

def find_dupes(startdirs):
    """ Find the duplicates in a list of starting directories """
    fnamedict = defaultdict(list)  # Dictionary of filenames to paths
    for root in startdirs:
        print("Processing Tree Under:", root)
        get_fnames(fnamedict, root)
    print("Checking names for duplicates")
    print_dups(fnamedict)

if __name__ == "__main__":  # Only run if started directly rather than imported
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:  # No start points provided
        sys.argv.append(".")
        print("Scanning for duplicate names under current directory")
    find_dupes(sys.argv[1:])
```

If you save the above into a file called something like `find_dup_names.py` and set the executable flags with `chmod` you will be able to call it with a list of directory names or without *in which case it will recurse the current directory.* If you place the file somewhere that is on your path you will not need to supply the path to it every time you use it.